# 'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Cosmos' and no accessible extension method 'Cosmos' accepting a first argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

While migrating a class library project from .netcore2.2 to .netcore 3.1, I am getting the following error:

> Error  CS1061  'IMutableEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Cosmos' and no accessible extension method 'Cosmos' accepting a first argument of type 'IMutableEntityType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In the **.netcore2.2** project I have used the following nuget packages:

1. AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos
4. Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Now as part of the migration process I have updated all the above nuget packages to their latest versions.

[image]

Her goes my DbContext class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }

    protected MyDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set;}

    public DbSet<Languages> Languages { get; set;}

    public DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set;}


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OneCollectionPerDbSet(modelBuilder);
    }

    private void OneCollectionPerDbSet(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var dbSets = typeof(MyDbContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
        foreach (var dbSet in dbSets)
        {
            var metadata = modelBuilder.Entity(dbSet.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]).Metadata;
            metadata.Cosmos().ContainerName = dbSet.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am getting error in the method: OneCollectionPerDbSet as shown in the below line:

```
metadata.Cosmos().ContainerName = dbSet.Name;
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue by providing their guidance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In EF Core 3.0+ provider extension methods like `Cosmos()`, `SqlServer()` etc. as well as `Relational()` have been removed. Now they are provided as direct extension methods of the corresponding metadata interfaces, with all previous properties replaced with `Get` / `Set` extension methods.

In your case, the replacement of `Cosmos().ContainerName` property are [GetContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmosentitytypeextensions.getcontainer?view=efcore-3.1) and [SetContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.cosmosentitytypeextensions.setcontainer?view=efcore-3.1) extension methods:

```
metadata.SetContainer(dbSet.Name);
```